# Non responsive popup quiet often in fedora 37

Tags: linux, fedora

I have fedora 37*(same issue was with 36 as well)*. **I get non responsive popup for applications quiet often**.Most of the time it last for couple of seconds. Sometimes it will come up repeatedly, sometimes not for hours. Doesn't seems to be one applications specified. It came up in many apps.
I'm not running out resources. I have plenty of RAM remaining when that happens. Also CPU doesn't seems to be max out either.
I couldn't find out the reason.Any idea how to fix it ?

PS: I have windows in the same laptop as duel boot , it doesn't have the same problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.